# Always success on ajax post with HttpResponseMessage 401

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-web-api, httpresponse

I always get `statusCode=200` on ajax post at client side, while servers answers with `HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized`.

My controller code:

```
public class AccountApiController : ApiController
{
    public HttpResponseMessage Login(HttpRequestMessage request, [FromBody]LoginViewModel loginModel)
    {
        return request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized, "Unauthorized login.");
    }
}
```

My ajax code:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/api/accountapi/login',
    type: 'POST',
    data: data
    })
    .done(function (object, status, xhr) {
        alert("Success: " + xhr.status + " : " + xhr.statusText);
    })
    .always(function (object) {
        $("#output").text(JSON.stringify(object, null, 4));
    });
```

Result: alert with text `Success: 200 : OK`
and output window with:

```
{
    "Message": "Unauthorized login."
}
```

So, I can get text error message, but i need to get HttpStatusCode to handle error statements. Help me, please.

More information about this issue and elegant solution from Brock Allen:
http://brockallen.com/2013/10/27/using-cookie-authentication-middleware-with-web-api-and-401-response-codes/

Comment: Use your developer tools to view the request/response properties. In chrome go to the network tab, make the request, inspect the Request URL and Status Code.

Comment: I got: `Request URL:http://localhost:31757/api/accountapi/login
Request Method:POST
Status Code:200 OK` and `X-Responded-JSON:{"status":401,"headers":{"location":"http:\/\/localhost:31757\/Account\/Login?ReturnUrl=%2Fapi%2Faccountapi%2Flogin"}}`. JSON answer looks like right way to dig in:)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It might be that your page is redirecting to a login page by the forms authentication module as soon as you return `HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized`.

From MSDN:

> All unauthenticated users are denied access to any page in your
>   application. If an unauthenticated user tries to access a page, the
>   forms authentication module redirects the user to the logon page
>   specified by the loginUrl attribute of the forms element.

The login page, or whatever page it's being redirected to, is then served with status code 200.

Comment: Everything set to allowanonymous. But page is not redirecting anyway:(

Comment: Just as a test, try changing the StatusCode to anything other then Unauthorized and see if that works. I fear that this is by design in the form authentication module.

Comment: I suspect that you override allowanonymous since you return Unauthorize anyways, so they aren't allowed after all.

Comment: Magnus, thanks, 404 and 403 works as expected. So the problem exists only with 401.

Comment: Happy to help! Sadly it didn't solve your problem, but hopefully it provided what you need to proceed :)

Comment: It really looks like the problem is inside forms authorization model, at least I can handle authorize error with another code (not elegant but works). So you saved my day:)

Answer (score 12):

Because a status of 200 is being returned, but the user is not authorized, another option is to check for X-Responded-JSON with a status of 401 in your javascript.

```
.done(function (object, status, xhr) {
      if (xhr.getResponseHeader("X-Responded-JSON") != null 
          && JSON.parse(xhr.getResponseHeader("X-Responded-JSON")).status == "401") {
          //some message here
          return;
     }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

To elaborate on Valin's comment, and inline Brock Allen's solution.

The clue lies in the returned OK response which internally traps the redirect to a form login:

```
X-Responded-JSON: {"status": 401, "headers": {"location":"http:\/\/localhost:50004\/Login?ReturnUrl=%2FClient"}}
```

If you'd like to fix on the server, instead of scraping the response for this internal error state, you can use  the solution from **Brock Allen**'s article on [Using cookie authentication middleware with Web API and 401 response codes](https://brockallen.com/2013/10/27/using-cookie-authentication-middleware-with-web-api-and-401-response-codes/):

> Normally when using cookie authentication middleware, when the server (MVC or WebForms) issues a 401, then the response is converted to a 302 redirect to the login page (as configured by the LoginPath on the [**CookieAuthenticationOptions**](https://brockallen.com/2013/10/24/a-primer-on-owin-cookie-authentication-middleware-for-the-asp-net-developer/)). But when an Ajax call is made and the response is a 401, it would not make sense to return a 302 redirect to the login page. Instead you’d just expect the 401 response to be returned. Unfortunately this is not the behavior we get with the cookie middleware — the response is changed to a 200 status code with a JSON response body with a message:
>
> ```js
> {"Message":"Authorization has been denied for this request."}
> ```
>
> I’m not sure what the requirement was for this feature. To alter it, you must take over control of the behavior when there is a 401 unauthorized response by configuring a CookieAuthenticationProvider on the cookie authentication middleware:
>
> ```
> app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
> {
>    AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
>    LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
>    Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
>    {
>       OnApplyRedirect = ctx =>
>       {
>          if (!IsAjaxRequest(ctx.Request))
>          {
>             ctx.Response.Redirect(ctx.RedirectUri);
>          }
>      }
>    }
> });
> ```
>
> Notice it handles the OnApplyRedirect event. When the call is not an Ajax call, we redirect. Otherwise, we do nothing which allows the 401 to be returned to the caller.
>
> The check for IsAjaxRequest is simply copied from a [**helper**](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetKatana/blob/v3.1.0/src/Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies/Provider/DefaultBehavior.cs#L36) in the katana project:
>
> ```
> private static bool IsAjaxRequest(IOwinRequest request)
> {
>    IReadableStringCollection query = request.Query;
>    if ((query != null) && (query["X-Requested-With"] == "XMLHttpRequest"))
>    {
>       return true;
>    }
>    IHeaderDictionary headers = request.Headers;
>    return ((headers != null) && (headers["X-Requested-With"] == "XMLHttpRequest"));
> }
> ```

Comment: This is the answer I've been looking for. Excellent solution - thank you for sharing!