# ASP.NET Identity (MVC 5) returns 200 for ajax request if unauthorized

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

I'm using ASP.NET Identity (MVC 5) and if the user isn't longer authorized the ajax requests will return 200 instead of 302 (redirect) or 401 (unauthorized).

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions {
    AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
    LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
    ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(20),
    SlidingExpiration = true,
    Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider {
        OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, ApplicationUser, int>(
            validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(15),
            regenerateIdentityCallback: (manager, user) => user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager), getUserIdCallback: (id) => (id.GetUserId<int>())),

    }
});
```

Authorize via FilterConfig:

```
public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters) {
    filters.Add(new AuthorizeAttribute());
}
```

simple ajax-form:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Index2", "Home", null, new AjaxOptions {
    InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
    HttpMethod = "POST",
    UpdateTargetId = "content",
}, new { id = "Test" })) {

    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <input type="submit" value="Submit Data" id="btnSubmit" />
}
```

If I login into application it works as expected. If I remove the **.AspNet.ApplicationCookie** then it returns a 200 status code

```
HTTP/2 200 OK
cache-control: private
server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
x-aspnetmvc-version: 5.2
x-aspnet-version: 4.0.30319
x-responded-json: {"status":401,"headers":{"location":"https:\/\/localhost\/TestApp\/Account\/Login?ReturnUrl=%TestApp%2FHome%2FIndex2"}}
x-powered-by: ASP.NET
date: Tue, 16 Jun 2020 14:36:49 GMT
content-length: 0
X-Firefox-Spdy: h2
```

If I check the Application_EndRequest() in Global.asax it also has the 200 status code. I can just see in the reponse above that is a x-responded-json with the 401. But ajax error function `error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError)` isn't called.

I just know solution like this in case of formsauthentication: https://www.codeproject.com/articles/1056969/asp-mvc-handle-ajax-errors-properly

But I can't use this for ASP.NET Identity because the response would be 200 code and not 302.

How can I solve this with ASP.NET Identity (MVC5)? At the moment I will get an empty response...

Answer (score 0):

The 200 just means the call was made without error. The 302 is probably not there because you are using ajax calls, also, the session has expired. One way to prevent ajax calls into your middleware when a user's authorization has expired would be to check the for an auth in the header or whatever mechanism you use in a global ajax handler. These global handlers fire before any other events attached so you can prevent propagation if the user is not authorized.

```
$(document).ajaxError(function (event, jqxhr, settings, data) {
    _ajaxHandler.handleAjaxError(event, jqxhr, settings, data);
});
$(document).ajaxSuccess(function (event, jqxhr, settings, exception) {
    _ajaxHandler.handleAjaxSuccess(event, jqxhr, settings, exception)
});
```

Comment: Prevoiusly I have used FormsAuthentication in my other projects - there was no different between traditional posts and ajax calls. The ajax calls just returned the login page and with a solution like the link in my post I was able to return the right status code. I suppose that there is some different behaviour with ASP.NET Identity. Thank you for your suggestion, but wouldn't it be better to check the `x-responded-json` which contains the 401 instead of checking the authentication cookies?

Comment: If the ASP.NET pipeline is shut down as in your session has expired, ajax calls can still be made to your controllers. Without the pipeline, northing is enforcing redirects. Are you adding your authorization attributes at each call or the class level of your controllers?

Comment: I'm setting the AuthorizeAttribute inside the RegisterGlobalFilters. I found following page: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20662608/always-success-on-ajax-post-with-httpresponsemessage-401 so I think there are two options. 1) like your suggestion checking the `X-Responded-JSON` for the 401 or 2) anwser of KyleMit of the above link > using the `OnApplyRedirect` will return the 401 code.